# How to Integrate with VMAX ads service?

Tags: android, admob

One of my client asking to integrate with VMAX ads services. If anyone has information how to setup and integrate with XML/via code

Below link is direct guide from VMAX.
But I need if anyone successfully integrated and ads are loading fine ?
Link:
http://www.vmax.com/2016/04/14/admob-integration-using-android-sdk

Comment: 1-start a new android studio project,select Google AdMob Ads Activity.

Comment: and read the code of project....